# Over current protection for a 1-cell battery

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, batteries

I have a one-cell battery which protection circuitry is based on a DW01-P (with dual mosfet 8205S).

[image]

The [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf) says on page 2 "Overcurrent detection voltage = 150mV". How do I translate this number into how much current (expressed in Ampere) that this one-cell lipo battery can discharge at maximum before it cuts off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look in the data sheet for the DW01-P. One copy can be found here:

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf

The device senses on the CS pin using a preset fixed voltage threshold. The discharge current limit is determined by the MOSFETs that you select. For quick reference here is the relevant text from the data sheet.

> **Selection of External Control MOSFET**
>   Because the overcurrent protection voltage is preset, the threshold current for overcurrent detection is determined by the turn-on resistance of the charge and
>   discharge control MOSFETs. The turn-on resistance of the external
>   control MOSFETs can be determined by the equation:
>
> RON = VOIP / (2 x IT)
>
> (IT is the overcurrent threshold current). For example, if the
>   overcurrent threshold current IT is designed to be 3A, the turn-on
>   resistance of the external control MOSFET must be 25mΩ. Be aware that
>   turn-on resistance of the MOSFET changes with temperature variation
>   due to heat dissipation. It changes with the voltage between gate and
>   source as well. (Turn-on resistance  of  MOSFET increases as the
>   voltage between gate and source decreases). As the  turn-on resistance
>   of the external MOSFET changes, the design of the overcurrent
>   threshold current changes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question stated here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272947/remove-over-current-protection-of-battery-protection-circuit Any idea?