# Remove over-current protection of battery protection circuit

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, batteries

I have a hardware that is powered by a standard polymer battery (http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-7V-Polymer-Rechargeable-Battery-2000mAh-PCM-103450-for-GPS-ipod-Tablet-PC-MP3-/262605237924).

The hardware draws a lot of current, more than 3A, perhaps up to 5A. This triggers the overcurrent protection of this battery. The protection circuitry includes two SOT23-6L (http://www.phaselink.com/QA/SOT23-6L.pdf) ICs:

- DW01-P (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf)
- 8205 (http://www.ait-ic.com/uploads/2011-01/05/_1294200000_5amsl7.pdf), corresponding to M1 and M2 of typical circuit below.

[image]

As replied on this question ([Over current protection for a 1-cell battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/over-current-protection-for-a-1-cell-battery)), the overcurrent protection is probably set up for 3A (25mohm ron of mosfets).

I would like to "decrease" the overcurrent protection up to 5A without losing the overdischarge protection. My options are:

- either replacing the dual mosfets. But I can't find any SOT23-6L with Ron=10mohm. 25mohm seems to be the minimum.
- or shorten M1 to disable the overcurrent protection. But I think it will disable the overdischarge detection voltage.

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: it is possible to reduce RdsOn but also possible to create a new problem with T['C] rise in the battery due to increased Pd=I^2ESR in the battery ( * Rth thermal resistance), where ESR rises with age, %DoD and inverse with Ah capacity

Comment: http://diodes.com/_files/datasheets/DMN1019USN.pdf

Comment: +1 for excellent documentation and clear problem formulation.

Comment: Are you sure it is safe to draw 5A from that battery? Is it just a short-term burst?

Comment: @mkeith 100ms burst from time to time.

Comment: @tony-stewart-ee-since-75 Good suggestion. But unfortunately, the SOT23-6 package of DMN1019 is only ONE mosfet. There is a 3-pin package which might be a solution if I solder two properly.

Comment: OK. I wouldn't expect a 100ms burst to be a problem provided the long-term average is reasonable.

Comment: A lot of dead links in question and discussion..

Answer (score 2):

The circuit looks for voltage drop across two power mosfets. It looks like the sensing circuit is between CS pin and GND pin.

Instead of looking for MOSFETs with lower Rdon, you can make a divider, splitting the R2 in two resistors, and connect the CS pin to the middle of the divider. The voltage between CS and GND will drop, IC will think that the current is small, and will trigger the overcurrent threshold at higher drop-through voltage.

Just try to connect another 1k resistor between CS and GND, and see if the cell will deliver more current before cut-off.

Comment: I am studying the DW01-P so I come to this post. This is an old post but I still want to comment to help other people if they come to here like me in the future. I believe changing R2 cannot change the overcurrent threshold, because the datasheet said it is used for: "latch-up protection when charger is connected under overdischarge condition and overstress protection at reverse connecting of a charger." Also the R2 is connected in series to the negative input of a comparator in the block diagram, changing its value will not change the sensed voltage at the comparator.

Comment: @eepty, you misunderstood. I am not suggesting to "change R2", I am suggesting to make a voltage divider on CS pin, since *"In normal mode, the DW01-P continuously monitors the discharge current by sensing the voltage of CS pin. If the voltage of CS pin exceeds the overcurrent protection voltage (VOIP) beyond the overcurrent delay time (TOI1) period, the overcurrent protection circuit operates and ..."*. According to block diagram, all thresholds are relative to GND pin. Therefore a voltage divider on CS pin will shift all thresholds, including overcurrent threshold into desired direction.

Comment: i tried connecting 1k resistor between CS and GND pin making a voltage divider as you suggested. and now i am able to draw more current but it has also disturb other feature which are controlled by CS pin like short circuit and also charger detector.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using the protection circuit ([DW01A](https://hmsemi.com/downfile/DW01A.PDF) + [DUAL MOSFET 8205A](https://www.maritex.com.pl/product/attachment/91261/8205A.pdf)) for the Li-Ion battery used inside the haircut machine (too much current flowed at the switching on). After reading the documentation, I followed a simple solution.Overcurrent protection voltage is about 150mV (DW01A) and Rds(on) is about 0.03ohm (MOSFET 8205A) so the max current is about 5A for one MOSFET (2.5A for DUAL MOSFET). So for increase max current by two i just moved the resistor R2 between drains of DUAL MOSFET 8205A and CS pin of DW01A.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Neat trick.....