# Battery Protection MOSFET 8205A Replacement

Tags: power, batteries, mosfet, protection, powermosfet

I am planning to add battery protection to a schematic for a project that is using the Panasonic NCR18650B 3400mAh 3.7V 18650 Li-ion Battery.  The protected version of this battery uses the protection circuit outlined in this post

[Dual mosfet 8205A - lithium battery protection circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/dual-mosfet-8205a-lithium-battery-protection-circuit)

I have difficulty sourcing the Dual Mosfet-8025A in the EU with a short lead time. Does anyone know where I can purchase this Mosfet. Have tried the usual suppliers such as Farnel, RS, Mouser, Digikey etc.  Or is anyone aware of a suitable MOSFET for this part available on Farnel, RS, Mouser, Digikey. I am novice when comes to electronics and have struggled to identify a suitable alternative

Comment: Looking up the part number, it seems there are two different parts with the number 8205A. One is a dual N-channel MOSFET as you described, but one is an all-in-one battery protection circuit. Do you know for sure which one you have? What package is it in? How many pins does it have?

Comment: If it is just a dual N-MOSFET, any dual N-MOSFET with similar ratings should work. The particular one you mention has the drains of the two FETs connected internally, but getting one with the FETs disconnected and connecting them externally with a short length of wire should work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a general part search - there is a website called [Octopart](https://octopart.com/) that can be used to find suppliers of a given component.

For the specific part you are after (8205A dual MOSFET) [Octopart](https://octopart.com/search?q=8205A&start=0) does not come up with the part you are after.

I turned to Google and found that your part can be bought from AliExpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Smd-8205s-8205a-sot23-6-lithium-battery-protect-ic-20pcs-free-shipping/1977980871.html

This gives us the following information about the part:
[image: 8205A Datasheet 1]
[image: 8205A Datasheet 2]

> **From this I found a compatible part from DiodesInc:**
>   [DMG9926UDM](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31770.pdf) [(DigiKey)](https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/DMG9926UDM-7/DMG9926UDMDICT-ND/2095675)

And a similar part with ESD protection:
[DMG6968UDM](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31758.pdf)  [(DigiKey)](https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/DMG6968UDM-7/DMG6968UDMDICT-ND/2075462)

There are many other suitable dual MOSFETs on each suppliers website. Alternatively, you don't need a dual MOSFET, you could simply just use 2 seperate N-ch MOSFETs.